# Copy iCloud file to sandbox

Tags: ios, icloud, nsfilemanager, nsfilecoordinator

I'm looking for a better way to download a bunch of files from my iCloud container to my sandbox. This is what I currently use:

```
for (FileAttachments *fileLink in items) {
        NSURL *cloudFileURL = [fileLink urlForCloudAttachmentWithName];

        NSURL *fileURL = [backupCloudLocalDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: fileLink.fileName];

        NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];

        [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:fileURL options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges error:&error

                                             byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {

                   NSError *blockError = nil;

                   [fileManager copyItemAtURL:cloudFileURL toURL:fileURL error:&blockError];
                                }];
        }
}
```

Is there any problem with making a copy of the iCloud item this way? In production, I have some  users complaining that all their files weren't downloaded. Is it better to use `NSFileManager's startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error` instead? If so, why?
Thanks.

Comment: Before running the code above, have you done anything to make sure that the file has been downloaded?

Comment: Or maybe a better way to put it is, how do you find the URLs for cloud files, so that you know what URL you're trying to copy from?

Comment: The URLs are saved in Core Data from when the files were added to the app. They hold a valid reference to the file; it's just that they're not getting downloaded in some cases, and not reproducible-y. Shouldn't it work from a fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL block?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's still not completely clear to me from comments how you're discovering the URLs, however some important details that affect your situation are:

1. Using `coordinateReadingItemAtURL:block:` has *nothing* to do with downloading files from iCloud. The purpose of `NSFileCoordinator` is to coordinate among readers and writers of a file so that, for example, you don't get two threads trying to write to the same file at the same time. You use file coordinators with iCloud because the iCloud system needs to read and write files and so does your app. Using a coordinator avoids corrupting the file, but again, has nothing to do with downloading the file.
2. To download a file from iCloud you need to use `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:` and then wait until the file downloads. The normal flow here is:

   a. Use `NSMetadataQuery` to find files that exist in the iCloud account

   b. Use `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:` to make sure they're available on the local device.

   The reason you need to use this call is simply because that's how iCloud works on iOS. Files don't download until you ask them to download, and this is how you ask. [On OS X it's different, everything automatically downloads.]
3. You *cannot* simply copy from an iCloud URL to another location unless you already know that the file has been downloaded. The file-copy operation does not download the file, so if the file isn't available locally, the copy will fail.

Comment: The URLs are saved when the files were added into the app, and then uploaded to iCloud (using setUbiquitous). All these files should always be stored in iCloud during the use of the app ... only in this one use-case, when the user is doing a backup, this code tries to bring all the files into the sandbox and throw them into a zip file. So when you say "the file isn't available locally", the files aren't available locally ever (unless you mean they're in some iCloud cache on device which I'm not aware of). So why would it work most of the time, and only fail occasionally?

Comment: If you can open and use a file, **then it is available locally**. It's impossible to open a document unless it exists on the local device. That's what "download" means in this context, that the file has been downloaded from iCloud to the local device. If the files "aren't available locally ever" then you cannot ever use those documents in any way, except to request a download.

Comment: As for why it would work sometimes but not always, it's impossible to say without a detailed analysis of your code. But a likely scenario is that it *works* when the document was created locally, and is still available on the local device. It *fails* during this backup operation because it's the one time that the user tries to grab everything, including non-downloaded files, and you're not downloading those files.

Comment: The only time I reference the iCloud file (after it's been uploaded) is to show it within a QLPreviewController. This doesn't require me to use startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error: and it works just fine. I suppose for backup purposes, i should use the startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL API instead of just doing a coordinated read-and-copy. BTW, does startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL download the file into the local sandbox? Or is it placed in some special iCloud cache? The API only asks for an item AT the URL but not where it'll deposit the file locally.

Comment: After download, the file is at the URL you provide. But that URL really needs to be one that you got from `NSMetadataQuery`, not one that you choose. This URL will be somewhere below `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:`.

Comment: Not clear about this: it HAS to be from NSMetadataQuery vs. a URL created with URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier + path of the file in iCloud? Also, I guess by "available locally", it means the private directory that the iCloud daemon uses, not somewhere in the app's sandbox. That part makes sense now.

Comment: The way Apple created the iCloud APIs and the way they are documented as crap and how the work poorly, makes these, without any doubt, the worst APIs, framework and documentation Apple ever dumped in the wild. Someone should give them a trophy.

Comment: I decided stop filling bug reports last year, after filling almost 100 bug reports and seeing that they don't do anything.

Comment: Ad 1. - not entirely true. See Apple's documentation: `If the device has not yet downloaded the file at the given URL, this method blocks (potentially for a long time) while the file is downloaded. If the file cannot be downloaded, this method fails. Alternatively; use a metadata query to check for the NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey key, and then call the startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error: method to download the file before trying to read it.` According to this, the file coordinator *should* download the file before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a metadata query to identify the files and their download status then, if they have not been downloaded initiate the download, and using the metadata query determine when the download is complete and then copy the file from the ubiquity container to the apps sandbox directory using a file coordinator.  If you try copying the file while it's partially downloaded you may get some strange results.

Comment: The problem is that the copy is done within a FileCoordinator's coordinateReadingItemAtURL block. Why wouldn't it work in that case?

Comment: I can't recall the detail but when dealing with iCloud files I seem to recall you must use metadata queries and you must initiate downloads - read the Apple docs to confirm.  In any event I use this approach with the sample apps here for backing and restoring Core Data files - see if they work for you and then use the same approach for your files.  http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you.

My case is that: When network disconnects, iCloud service copy file from iCloud container to sandbox. When this line executes, it can not go into the block to copy file. This is the reason why this file can not be copied.

> ```
> fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:fileURL options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL)
> ```

My solution is: Before copying file from iCLoud container to sandbox, you must check network. If it is not available, don't execute this code (return method). If network connects, execute fileCoordinator and copy.

More info: When copy file from ICloud container to sandbox, method fileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:error: is OK because I implement this method and it's good.

Hope this works.

Comment: If status NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey is NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent(already downloaded to local iCloud container) then also, it will be needed to use fileCoordinator Reading from url? @nmh